# Contradictory information for Copy Editor progress

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, review, edit-badges

For some time now, the progress towards the Copy Editor Badge is being displayed at https://stackoverflow.com/review/

I guess a screenshot tells the whole story:

[image: Contradictory Copy Editor progress]

Red emphasis mine. The text proclaims a target of 400 edits, while the mouseover claims 500. Which will it be?

I can only report on SO as I don't have enough edits on other sites to see the Copy Editor countdown, but other sites are probably affected, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's the number of edits you've made, not the number you require. I see this:
[image]

Comment: Oh. Now I feel stupid. I wasn't aware I had edited that many posts already. I guess I can delete this post. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @erwin Don't delete it. It's fine, and could help someone later. Besides, we've all asked halfway silly questions now and again.